Finding the next available time slot for a location and a trade
I'm in the middle of a tricky scheduling problem, and wondered if anyone could lend some guidance.
We have several thousand locations in which we are carrying out work, and each location can only have 4 people in it at one time.
We have a number of different types of trades (e.g. Joiner, Electrician, Plumber) and there are a limited number of each of those as well.
There is a whole set of tasks, which requires 1 or more tradespeople (of a set type) and the task is to be done in a certain location.
Each task has a specific duration (this duration varies between tasks).
In order to simplify things, I have created a table, which is structured as follows:
id - INT(11) - unique ID, incrementing
projectid - INT(11) - ID of the project in question
l4_start - DATETIME - Start of the Task
l4_end - DATETIME - End of the Task
locationid - INT(11) - ID of the location
taskid - INT(11) - ID of the task
trade - VARCHAR(50) - the tradesperson type (e.g. LAB_ELECTRICIAN)
people - INT(11) - how many of the tradesperson of that type required for that task

As the system is planning the next task, it needs to find the next available slot in that location.
A slot is valid if:

it has less than the number of people in that location for the duration of the task so we don't overfill the room with tradespeople
we have enough available tradespeople of that type (across all locations) for the duration of the task.

In order to generate a sequenced set of timeslots to check (of the specific duration of this specific task), I've been using the MariaDB sequence, and then trying to join that to the planner table to see how many people are in each location, and how many of each trade are in use during each slot - and then sorting and getting the first slot which has both conditions valid.
This does work. However, it is massively slow - around 30 seconds per query. I really need it to be sub-second if possible.
Here is the query currently:
SELECT mystart, myend, SUM(IF(vessellocationid='158533',people,0)) AS peopleinlocation
   , SUM(IF(trade = 'LAB_ELECTRICIAN',people,0)) AS tradecount 
FROM (SELECT  '2024-05-17 07:00:00' + INTERVAL seq-1 MINUTE AS mystart,
         '2024-05-17 07:30:00' + INTERVAL seq-1 MINUTE AS myend 
      FROM seq_1_to_10000_step_5
     ) AS searchrange
 
JOIN tbl_project_planner AS planner
  ON (vessellocationid='158533' OR trade = 'LAB_ELECTRICIAN') 
  AND projectid='21011' 
  AND (
        (planner.l4_start BETWEEN searchrange.mystart AND searchrange.myend
         OR planner.l4_end BETWEEN searchrange.mystart AND searchrange.myend
        )
      OR planner.l4_start <= searchrange.mystart AND planner.l4_end >= searchrange.myend
     )
GROUP BY mystart
HAVING IFNULL(peopleinlocation,0) <=4 
   AND IFNULL(tradecount,0) <= 5 


I have indexes on l4_start, l4_end, trade, vessellocationid, projectid
Output from EXPLAIN is showing
1   SIMPLE  planner index_merge projectid,vessellocationid,trade,v_t_p,l4_start,l4_end,l4_start and end vessellocationid,projectid,projectid,trade  5,5,5,203   NULL    918 Using union(intersect(vessellocationid,projectid),intersect(projectid,trade)); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

1   SIMPLE  seq_1_to_10000_step_5   index   NULL    PRIMARY 8   NULL    2000    Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)

Any advice welcomed, I'm stumped! Thanks so much in advance

I would try using (LEFT) joins instead of the IF statements. i.e JOIN to "vessel" and "trade" tables, which will hopefully filter down the rows that it has to process. In other words, help the database filter down the rows to exactly what it needs first, then do the processing on it (SUM etc.)

application time periods and set data type might help with this problem

@danblack Thank you for this. The application time periods looks like it is a form of unique index, and so I'm not sure that will help here, but I will take a look at the set data type. Is your thought there that MariaDB would be faster using an integer to represent a trade type for example?

@drone.ah Thank you for the reply. I did look at this, essentially having two sets of results (one for the location, another for the trade) but the issue was that both had to be joined to the sequence, and then the results joined together - and this ended up taking longer still. Joining with the sequence table seems to be taking the time, but I can't see any other way to achieve what we are trying to do...

@NickF, It might be simpler to do the query from another perspective - i.e get a list of booked timings against the number of people booked at those timings. You could then eliminate the sequence table. If that is quick enough, filter it based on the outside bounds (i.e. for the next x days, assuming you don't care about the past). Hopefully you have a small enough set now that you can process it outside the database, or try the sequence thing again
